# Cannot resolve symbol Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

The compiler won't resolve any of the Firebase classes despite me adding the implemetations in build.gradle

App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google ()
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.2.0'

    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In main activity the IDE cant resolve any of these classes and the compilation fails

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private FirebaseAuth mFirabaseAuth;
```

I have synced project with gradle files, I have tried clean project, I have tried rebuild project.

Comment: The last one should be `FirebaseAuth` and not `FirabaseAuth`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This did not fix the error I was having how ever. But I did get it fixed by changing firebase-database:16.0.1 to 16.0.0 and then back to 16.0.1. Strange

Answer (score 0):

Click File->Sync Project with Gradle Files

Had the same issue, and this fixed it for me.

If it still doesn't work, try doing a rebuild too.

Answer (score 0):

In app build.gradle
Add dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call Firebase object, and are getting this error:

Error: Cannot resolve symbol Firebase

you might be missing a dependency.

Make sure you add com.firebase:firebase-client to your dependencies in your app gradle:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are just copy-pasting the code from the firebase docs then add following libraries to your java file:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
```